# I have a field and I want to populate all its rows in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

how can I populate it without going to one row at the time? the field is a numeric field of 1 and 0 I want to populate all the rows with the value of 1. I just don't want to go one row at the time. and populate all at once any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following SQL:

```
update mytable
set myfield=1
```

Comment: SR. I tried UPDATE categories2 SET email_activated = 10 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.0004 sec )
UPDATE categories2 SET email_activated =1

Comment: Cero rows were affected I don't know why

Comment: I am using the SQL box to do it. inside phpmyadming. Not avail can't believe, hope I don't have a different version which I doubt it.

Comment: I was missing two commas in my mysql version UPDATE categories2 SET `email_activated` = '1'

Comment: @fello I think you mean quotes; in that case, it is not a numeric column as you indicated...

Comment: i thought it was a numeric column wait a minute... I am going to look at the structure

Comment: it is an enum('0','1') column

Comment: Redfielter How can I affect x row ? Update mytable SET myfield Felo=0?

Answer (score 2):

You could either write a query to do it:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = 1
```

Or just set it as the default value for that field. Assuming the field is null or empty this will fill it automatically, too.

Comment: Changed the default value to as Defined 1 and nothing yet I also did the update.

Comment: I am using the SQL box to do it. inside phpmyadming. Not avail can't believe, hope I don't have a different version which I doubt it.

Comment: I was missing two single quotes in my sql versions UPDATE categories2 SET `email_activated` = '1'

Comment: how can I affect only one row instead?

Comment: To affect only one row use a WHERE clause: UPDATE tablename SET columnname = 1 WHERE id = 10

Answer (score 0):

Some simple SQL you be enough

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourcolumn=1;
```

Comment: I am using the SQL box to do it inside phpmyadming. Not avail can't believe, hope I don't have a different version which I doubt it.

Comment: I was missing two single quotes in my sql versions UPDATE categories2 SET `email_activated` = '1'